# All used before

Tags: determiners

In the following sentence

> I am vexed at him for what all he has done for
>   him till date.

I think the above sentence is wrong because **all(determiner)** is placed before numbers, my, your etc

And hence it should be

For all what he has done

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I am vexed at him for all (that) he has done to date.

Comment: Is the usage of what incorrect?